# Jenkins: Active Choices Parameter + Groovy to build a list based on REST responde

Tags: rest, jenkins, groovy

I have a REST client that returns me a list of systems.
I need this list to be as a parameter for a jenkins job.

I think I need Actice Choices Parameter plugin with Groovy and HTTPBuilder in order to do that.

What do you guys think?
I did not find a way to install HTTPBuilder into Jenkins.

Is there any other way that you guys think it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same problem trying to parse parameters via groovy script. Arun's answer did not work for me. However, I have managed to get it to work using the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter
import java.net.URL
import java.net.URLConnection
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def choices = []
def url = new URL("some.data.url")
def conn = url.openConnection()
conn.setDoOutput(true)

def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))
def results = new JsonSlurper().parseText(reader.getText());
reader.close()

results.each { data -> choices.push(data.field) }
return choices.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

First paste the JSON body snapshot output -or whatever your REST client is going to return. That'll help.

**For ex:** if it'll return a JSON object then you can use Active Choice Parameter's Groovy script step - OR Scriptler script (within the Active Choice Parameter plugin). **PS:** Scriptler script runs in the same JVM of Jenkins process so it has access to Jenkins/etc object for free. You don't need HTTPBuilder or anything. See the code sample below.

Assuming if your REST client is returning a JSON object and from that object if you want to list hostname of the system or some **field name** then replace the following variable with that and you'll get it listed while doing "Build with parameters" from Jenkins job's dashboard.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//this will be your URL which will return something, tweak it if you want to pass parameters or username/password acc.

def SOME_URL = "https://koba.baby.com/some_url"

// now connect to the URL and create a connection variable 'conn'
def conn = SOME_URL.toURL().openConnection()

// create a list variable 'servernames'
def servernames = []

// if connection response was successful i.e. http protocol return code was 200, then do the following
if( conn.responseCode == 200 ) {
    // get the results / output of the URL connection in a variable 'results'
    def results = new JsonSlurper().parseText(conn.content.text)

    // to see results variable output uncomment the next line
    //println results

    // now read each element in the 'results' variable and pick servername/somefield variable into the list variable 'servernames'
    results.each { id, data -> servernames.push(data.someField_or_HostName) }
}
return servernames.sort().unique()
// return servernames.sort()
```