# Getting credentials and other parameters into Jenkins' ActiveChoice plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

The Active Choices Jenkins plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) allows someone to write a groovy script to return some dynamic options.

My script is something like this:

```
static String getDockerHubToken(String username, String password) {
  return ...;
}

static List getDockerHubTags(String jwtToken) {
  return ...;
}

def token = getDockerHubToken('myusername', 'mypassword')
def tagNames = getDockerHubTags(token)
return tagNames
```

(The implementation follows the pattern in [Jenkins: Active Choices Parameter + Groovy to build a list based on REST responde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549766/jenkins-active-choices-parameter-groovy-to-build-a-list-based-on-rest-respond))

So the question is:

- How can I get the username and password into this script from Jenkins credentials (instead of hard-coding them into the script, as I did above)?

Thanks!

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54927791/3730626). Basically you can try with the credentials plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M B wrote above, the way to do this is to:

- install and configure the credentials plugin.
- write code to access the Jenkins instance and the credentials natively.
- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54927791/1598730 for an example.

At the end, my code is:

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.*
import jenkins.model.*

static String getDockerHubToken(String username, String password) {
  return ...;
}

static List getDockerHubTags(String jwtToken) {
  return ...;
}

def instance = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance();
def dockerLogin = CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(StandardUsernameCredentials.class, instance, null, null).find {
    it.id == 'my-docker-login-credentials-id'
}
def token = getDockerHubToken(dockerLogin.username, dockerLogin.password.getPlainText())
def tagNames = getDockerHubTags(token)

return tagNames
```

Comment: We have a task to break down README into separated documentation files, to better organize the docs. But if anyone would like to send a PR to README now with this example, that'd be great as I think others could have the same question and this could be helpful: https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-choices-plugin/blob/master/README.md Cheers, Bruno.